# accord / concord usage

Tags: word-usage

What difference of sense would you hear in the following between "accord" and "concord":

"…all of whom remain within the enviable sphere of domestic accord/concord."

The OED is inconclusive, if not tautological, the first entry under "concord, n." making use of "accord:"

"1. Agreement between persons; concurrence in feeling and opinion; harmony, accord."

Answer (score 2):

In some ways, the two words mean the same thing in your example. It tells me that people are in agreement and everyone is "playing ***according*** to the rules".

However, ***concord*** means more than just agreement — it's a ***harmonious*** agreement. People aren't just following the rules, they're getting along with each other in a pleasant way.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://the-difference-between.com/accord/concord

"As nouns the difference between concord and accord is that concord is a state of agreement; harmony; union [or concord can be a variety of American grape, with large dark blue (almost black) grapes in compact clusters]; while accord is agreement or concurrence of opinion, will, or action.

While the references I checked support the use of "concord" in your example, it is a word I encounter in everyday writing or speech far less often than "accord." While unlikely to be confused in the example phrase as "…all of whom remain within the enviable sphere of [a] domestic grape," the use of "accord" is far more common, if less precise, and the frequency of use for "accord" has exceeded that for "concord" consistently according to Google Books Ngram Viewer.

(I don't know how to paste in the chart showing the use of the two words from 1700 to 2008, but here is the link: http://tinyurl.com/accord-vs-concord )